# Facebook PHP API not posting to fan page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am running a page that utilizes the Facebook PHP SDK to post a Facebook update to a Facebook fan page. I have setup the app, allowed full access (offline access, manage pages, stream update) to the user account, made sure I am the admin to the fan page and generated the access token. Here is the code I am using to test this:

```
$APP_ID = '****';                       
$APP_SECRET = '*****';          
$PAGE_ID = '****';                          
$ACCESS_TOKEN = '****';

//Initiate a facebook instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $APP_ID,
  'secret' => $APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
));

//To keep this as simple as possible, we'll only be posting a message to the wall with our access token we received from accounts
$attachment = array('message' => "test", 'access_token' => $ACCESS_TOKEN);

$result = $facebook->api('/'.$PAGE_ID.'/feed', 'post', $attachment);

if($result){ 
    echo "<p>Posted status update</p>";
}
```

This gives me a success message but does not actually post anything to anywhere. If I change this line:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$PAGE_ID.'/feed', 'post', $attachment);
```

to this:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);
```

It works like a charm and posts the update to the my Facebook wall, and not my fan page. All of the tutorials I have seen and questions I have read on here lead me to believe that my code should be posting to my fan page, what am I missing?

Comment: In my code I don't put the DS in front of the page_id, like this:  $result = $facebook->api($PAGE_ID.'/feed', 'post', $attachment);

Comment: Didn't make a difference for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your own Page, or are you trying to post to a page you're a fan of instead?

If this is your page, use the page access token you can retrieve at the `/me/accounts` endpoint to post as the page

If it's not, you must like the Page before you can post on its wall

Comment: Thanks, as it turns out I was using the access token for the app I had setup. I pulled everything using /me/accounts and thats where I noticed that the two did not match up as I was expecting.